# Styling the Quick Launch Menu SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, quick-launch

I would like to know how to come up with a Quick Launch Menu like this on SharePoint 2013 Online which has Accordian Style. How do I go about it?

[image]

Comment: How did you style your menu to look like that with the inverted bit (triangle) on the right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom css style and reference it through master page. For styling quick launch you can use following styles

```
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox UL.root > LI > .menu-item {
     /*Style each menu item*/
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > ul.root > li.static > ul.static > li.static > a:hover {
     /*Style on hove sub items*/
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > ul.root > li.selected > a { 
     /*Style selected top level item*/
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > ul.root > li > a:hover {  
     /*Style top level mouse hover*/
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > ul.root > li.static > ul.static > li > a { 
     /*Style sub level mouse hove*/
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > ul.root > li.static > ul.static > li > a.selected {  
     /*Style selected sub item*/
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox a.selected {
     /*Style Selected Item*/
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox UL.root UL {
     /*Style Outer Box*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Amal ! Question is, do you have an example of how this kind of styling is used. For better understanding visually?

Comment: Yes http://akashkarda.blogspot.com/2014/05/quick-launch-styles-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: And a link on how to put the CSS in the Master Page?

Comment: Its on the same article. Read the top section

Comment: How do get to the master page is the question I am kindly asking.

Comment: Its off-topic. Please post it as a different question.

Comment: Also, and adding the icons next to the Links as in the links?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19012/discussion-between-ngeshlew-and-amal-hashim).